# label tag and radio buttons not horizontal

Tags: html, css

I want to gender label and mail and female label and radio buttons put in a line -  why they are vertical? As default they must be horizontal.

```css
.regform {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: 'IRYekan', tahoma;
}

.regform fieldset {
  border: none;
}

.regform legend {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.regform input[type="text"],
.regform input[type="date"],
.regform input[type="datetime"],
.regform input[type="email"],
.regform input[type="number"],
.regform input[type="search"],
.regform input[type="time"],
.regform input[type="url"],
.regform textarea,
.regform select {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'IRYekan', tahoma;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.regform input[type="text"]:focus,
.regform input[type="date"]:focus,
.regform input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.regform input[type="email"]:focus,
.regform input[type="number"]:focus,
.regform input[type="search"]:focus,
.regform input[type="time"]:focus,
.regform input[type="url"]:focus,
.regform textarea:focus,
.regform select:focus {
  background: #d2d9dd;
}

.regform .number {
  direction: rtl;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'IRYekan', tahoma;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.regform label {
  direction: rtl;
  display: block;
  color: #8a97a0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="regform">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><span class="number">1</span> Personal Info </legend>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Family">
      <div class="gender">
        <label>Gender:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
        <label for="male">male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
        <label for="female">Female</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you here by clicking the `<>` - it is much better to do that than on an external site

Comment: thanks i didn't know that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the labels are displayed as a block, delete that line from this class:

```
.regform label {
    direction:rtl;
    color:#8a97a0;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Example:

```css
.regform {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: 'IRYekan', tahoma;
}

.regform fieldset {
  border: none;
}

.regform legend {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.regform input[type="text"],
.regform input[type="date"],
.regform input[type="datetime"],
.regform input[type="email"],
.regform input[type="number"],
.regform input[type="search"],
.regform input[type="time"],
.regform input[type="url"],
.regform textarea,
.regform select {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'IRYekan', tahoma;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.regform input[type="text"]:focus,
.regform input[type="date"]:focus,
.regform input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.regform input[type="email"]:focus,
.regform input[type="number"]:focus,
.regform input[type="search"]:focus,
.regform input[type="time"]:focus,
.regform input[type="url"]:focus,
.regform textarea:focus,
.regform select:focus {
  background: #d2d9dd;
}

.regform .number {
  direction: rtl;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'IRYekan', tahoma;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.regform label {
  direction: rtl;
  color: #8a97a0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="regform">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><span class="number">1</span> Personal Info </legend>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Family">
      <div class="gender">
        <label>Gender:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
        <label for="male">male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
        <label for="female">Female</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've used `display: block` on your label, why? If you'd remove that, it works

```
.regform label {
  direction:rtl;
  color:#8a97a0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```